# Setting Up CKAN on AWS - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, wsgi, ckan

I'm trying to set up a basic CKAN site on AWS using the directions posted here: https://github.com/okfn/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-2.0-from-source-on-Ubuntu-12.04-on-EC2#create-ckan-users

After working my way through the tutorial, I'm sitting here staring at a 500 Internal Server Error page. Bummer.

I'm new to using Python for web applications and don't really understand wsgi scripts yet, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. Here's a traceback from my error log. Any hints about where I should be looking would be much appreciated. Cheers.

```
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] mod_wsgi (pid=13943): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/bin/mothership.py' can$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] mod_wsgi (pid=13943): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] Traceback (most recent call last):
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/bin/mothership.py", line 10, in <module>
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     fileConfig(config_filepath)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/util/logging_co$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/util/logging_co$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     h = apply(klass, args)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] mod_wsgi (pid=13942): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/bin/mothership.py' can$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] mod_wsgi (pid=13942): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] Traceback (most recent call last):
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/bin/mothership.py", line 10, in <module>
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     fileConfig(config_filepath)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/util/logging_co$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]   File "/home/ubuntu/public_html/mysite.com/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/util/logging_co$
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253]     h = apply(klass, args)
>[Wed Jul 24 21:02:40 2013] [error] [client 192.245.194.253] TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
```

Answer (score 3):

[This mailing thread seems to be the answer](http://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2013-June/005008.html). (I found it by googling for parts of the traceback.)

Your logging configuration in your configuration ini file. The logging args need to look like this apparently:

```
args = ("/var/log/ckan/[yoursite.com]/ckan.log", "a", 20000000, 9)
```